# Отловить завершение задачи через диспетчер задач

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть C# WinForms программа. Нужно отловить когда ее закрывают, если я сам ее закрываю то FormClosing, а если пользователь снимает задачу через диспетчер? Как мне это отловить и перед закрытием выполнить, то что мне нужно?

Comment: Достаточно зайти в [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Как таковое событие из самой формы отловить нельзя. Но можно создать ещё один процесс, который будет каким-либо образом реагировать на закрытие основной формы. Пример с такой реализацией: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20533/How-to-know-when-the-Task-Manager-kills-your-app (нажмите "Download source code"). Я попытался реализовать это через AppDomain.ProcessExit (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=net-5.0), но event не срабатывал при закрытии через диспетчер задач

Comment: @Frehzy AppDomain поддерживается полноценно только в старом .NET Framework 4.x